# Link requires to be clicked twice after jQuery slideUp()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem can be experienced after clicking 'See more' under the first element of my portfolio(Cluj School of Public Health). Another div will slideDown() from under the Portfolio heading, which will somehow cause any element from the portfolio previews to require two clicks rather than one when attempting to expand the preview.

I am using a plugin for the portfolio grid: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview

You can view the page in question here: http://www.zefirus.co.uk/

Here are the functions I wrote for closing the preview existing within the plugin and sliding down an additional div that I have created:

```
function hidePreview() {
        var preview = $.data( this, 'preview' );
        preview.close();
        $.removeData( this, 'preview' );
}

function public_max() {
    $('#public_max').slideDown(500);
    $('.unload').slideDown(300);
}

function gridSlideUp() {

    $(document.body).animate({
    'scrollTop':   $('#portofoliu').offset().top
    }, 300);
    setTimeout(public_max, 700);

}

function gridSlideDown() {
    $(document.body).animate({
    'scrollTop':  $('#portofoliu').offset().top
    }, 300);
    $('#og-grid').slideDown('slow');
    $('#og-grid').trigger(click());

}

function load_public() {
    hidePreview();
    setTimeout(gridSlideUp, 650);
}


function unload_public() {
    $('#public_max').slideUp(700);
    $('.unload').slideUp(300);
    setTimeout(gridSlideDown, 700);

}
```

Comment: This `$('#og-grid').trigger(click());` looks wrong at first glance

Comment: Also at the second one. Use `$('#og-grid').trigger('click');`

Comment: Do you know about the toggle() function ?

Comment: Indeed there was a mistake there, but I only built the trigger so that I simulate 1 click on og-grid so that the user only needs to click once to expand. This would have been some sort of temporary solution but I've corrected the code and it still does nothing. Thanks for the replies guys, still open to any suggestions..

Comment: Update: I've managed to fix it by using the code Itay and espascarello previously suggested, but I'm thinking that I could maybe find out the source of this issue so that I avoid incorporating such code fireworks to prevent it from glitching under certain circumstances perhaps.. If anyone has any idea of why this problem may have started occuring in the first place, I would be very grateful if you would let me know. Thanks!